# How to get directory of the dib file in a Polyglot notebook?

Tags: powershell, polyglot-notebooks

When using Polyglot notebooks (previously known as dot net interactive notebooks) with PowerShell, how do I get the directory of the executing file in this ecosystem?

In (raw) PowerShell I would use $PSScriptRoot (or $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path), is there an equivalent in Polyglot notebooks?

I am currently storing it like this for later use, but I'd bet there is a more idiomatic way of doing it in notebooks.

`$currentDirectory = Get-Location`

Comment: You can use the automatic `$PWD` variable to get the current location too

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, I suppose I'm looking for the directory of the currently executing file, even if I have done a CD to another directory (which would change the PWD)